# Firebase redirect example from the docs throws error: Unexpected token. Why?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I wanted to add redirects to my firebase project, so I pasted [the example from the offical docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#capture-url-segments-for-redirects) as a test:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  "redirects": [ {
    "regex": "/blog/(?P<post>.+)",  // if you're familiar with PCRE, be aware that RE2 requires named capture groups to begin with ?P
    "destination": "https://blog.myapp.com/:post",  // includes the entire URL segment identified and captured by the `regex` value
    "type": 301
  }, {
    "regex": "/users/(\d+)/profile",  // uses the \d directive to only match numerical path segments
    "destination": "/users/:1/newProfile",  // the first capture group to be seen in the `regex` value is named 1, and so on
    "type": 301
  } ]
}
```

When I tried to deploy I got the error:

```
Error: There was an error loading firebase.json:

Unexpected token 'd' at 28:26
      "regex": "/users/(\d+)/profile",
                         ^
```

How come the official example gets a syntax error? What is the problem?

Comment: Have you maybe tried `\/users\/(\d+)`?

Comment: No, I copied the example as is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslash `\\d`.